# Div to show only on Ipad diplay

Tags: css, ipad

Is it possible to display DIV only for the iPad display?
I tried searching on Google and some of the solutions that appear here, but it does not work
It just displays it on your computer as well.
Is it possible that it will display only to the iPad display

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

*Thanks and sorry about my Englsih

Comment: have you tried adding another `@media` with `min-device-width: 1024px)` and just add the style `display: hidden` to your `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `display: none;` on the div so that it is hidden on all devices/screen sizes, then set the `display` to `block` for iPad portrait and landscape. You can also use any other type of display (e.g. `inline-block` if the div needs to be inline), just make sure it isn't `none` for the media query.

The following code should fix your issue, sourced form [here](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPad).

```
div {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  
{ 
    div {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

div{ 
display:none
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
div{
display : block
 }
}

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I dont know why i cant vote this but i accept this!thanks a lot!